# FN-Key Binding; what needs to be known?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've beeen trying to read some about how to bind the FN + *key* combos to do certain common actions (toggle wifi, toggle bluetooth, brightness up/down, toggle touchpad, mute/unmute, volume up/down, etc etc), but I can't grasp the basics; I'm really really new to Linux overall, so any specifics are off my understanding without previous explanation.

If i'm correct, I need to set the sequence scancode -> keycode -> keysymbol correctly for binding a key. How are these done ?

Are any of these system-specific or hardware-specific details? I have what seems a really standard keyboard (latam keyboard, with ñ)

Thanks in advance for any help provided.